# About the installation of Moses tool on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: installation, sudo, make, makefile

we are working on project related to language translation with the help of moses tool...but we are not able to install moses...we face some installation problems.
we make a directory on desktop named workingdir

Sir we install the initial packages:-

```
    $sudo apt-get install build-essential
    $sudo apt-get install subversion
    $sudo apt-get install tcl-dev
    $sudo apt-get install tclx8.4-dev
    $sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
    $sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-dev
    $sudo apt-get install csh
    $sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

then we have some steps to install moses,we use these steps to install moses,we attach the file with this mail...
then we download srilm.tgz from internet and extract that file...in Desktop/workingdir/srilm ...
then we go to the path---- Desktop/workingdir/srilm ...

```
$cd srilm
$tsch
```

here we type the command :-$ `make NO_TCL = X MACHINE_TYPE = i686 World`
we type the command like given below:-

> secg-ThinkCentre-Edge-71z:~/Desktop/workingdir/srilm> sudo  make
>   NO_TCL = X MACHINE_TYPE = i686 World [sudo] password for secg: make:
>   *** empty variable name.  Stop.

it shows the following error

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
make NO_TCL=X MACHINE_TYPE=i686 World
```

instead. When there are spaces around the `=`, make tries to parse the ‘empty string’ before it as a variable name, causing the “empty variable name” error message that you saw.